# Hover affect of tooltip also underlines text of content in span

Tags: html, css

**Edited:**

I have a tooltip icon that when you hover over it brings up a box with information which is fine. However, I also want this to underline text inside the contents of a span tag but I can't seem to apply the css to do both I can only seem to get it to do one or the other.

Below is the code for the tooltip icon:

**SCSS**

```
.tooltip-region {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 8;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px; 
}

.tooltip-region::before {
    content: '?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

.tooltip-region:hover p{
    display: block;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tooltip-region p{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    left: -4px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}

.tooltip-region p::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: blue;
    left:10px;
    top:-12px;
} 

.tooltip-region p::after {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    position: relative;
    top:-40px;
    left:0; 
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <form action="#">
       <div class="flexrow">
           <div class="tooltip-region">
           <p>Text</p>
           </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The code for the span I want to highlight is this:

**html**

```
<div class="grid-item-2">
   <pre id="terraCode"> 
region = "<span id="regionList" class="regionListUnderline"></span>"
   </pre>
</div>
```

I have JavaScript code that autofills the content of the span which is why the code above has no text in it.

But the css I want to apply to the contents of the span when I hover over the tooltip is this:

**SCSS**

```
.regionListUnderline:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

If anyone can see how I can apply the dotted line to the contents of the span when I hover over the tooltip icon would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more html to understand how the span and the div are placed in the dom? It is hard to fix css problems without knowing more about the nesting.

Comment: Sorry yep that's updated now

Comment: Ok, is the grid-item-2 in the grid-container?

Comment: Sorry yes it is

Comment: If the elements are not direct siblings, then this will be complicated without javascript. Are you open for a javascript solution?

Comment: Javascript is fine with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the style via *JavaScript*. Therefore you would have to add this to your script (make sure that the dom content has loaded):

```
const handleMouseOver = () => {
  const el = document.getElementById("regionList");
  el.style.borderBottom = "1px dotted black";
};

const handleMouseLeave = () => {
  const el = document.getElementById("regionList");
  el.style.borderBottom = "none";
};

const [tooltip] = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-region");
tooltip.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
tooltip.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave);
```

This will only work if you have one element with the class `tooltip-reqion` because the code targets the first of occurance. If you have several this would need more logic.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks very much :)

Comment: You should maybe also add a removeEventListener when the user exits the component for performance issues, I guess.